# using canvas.drawcircle to mark a point in google-maps android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-canvas

I want to mark certain points in google maps,I read http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

But the problem which I am facing is that, this method is useful when we want to show a image on top of google maps, however I want a circle which may have any given color.

Also I want to show a toast when user clicks circle(I know how this could be easily done if we use drawable)

I am unable to find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw a circle, you should create your custom class that extends Overlay, and override the draw method

```
 @Override
 public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setARGB(80,0,0,255);
            canvas.drawCircle( x,y,radius, paint);
 }//met
```

For the click, did you try to override ontap ?

Regards,
 Steff